# How can I list all projects in the current solution dependent on a given NuGet package?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a solution with 72 projects. I would like to list all projects from that solution that have a reference to given NuGet package. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the solution and select "Manage Nuget packager for solution" then click "Installed packages" select the package you want to see and click the Manage button. You will see all your projects and which use the selected Nuget package.

[image]

Comment: As an FYI - Projects that a developer manually referenced the package through References, will not show up in this list.

Comment: I don't get a Manage button... And my company blocks all the images on all SO sites (for some reason), so I can't even compare to what you get.